# Probability of not $C$ and $D$ occurring given $P(C)$, $P(D)$ and $P(C \cap D)$

Tags: probability

Let C and D be two events for which one knows that $P(C)=0.3$, $P(D) =
0.4$, and $P(C \cap D)=0.2$. What is $P(C' \cap D)$?

By intuition my guess is that
$$P(C' \cap D) = P(D) - P(C \cap D) = 0.2,$$

But I am unsure, I would also like to know a more analytical and rigorous proof.Thanks!

Comment: See [The Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

Answer (score 0):

Note that by the law of total probability
$$
P(D)=P(D|C')P(C')+P(D|C)P(C)
$$
which is $0.4=P(D|C')\times 0.7+P(D|C)\times 0.3$.

Here $$P(D|C)=\frac{P(D\cap C)}{P(C)}=\frac{0.2}{0.3}$$

So you can get $P(D\cap C')=P(D|C')P(C')$ now.